# Scroll parent to top from app part

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is it possible to scroll (iframe) parent to top from javascript of a app-part/addin-part?

Anyone with a **verfied** solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add **onload="window.parent.parent.scrollTo(0,0)"** to the body tag in app part.

Comment: nope, didnt work. Ive tried most of the "this might work?"-solutions, thats why I asked for a verified solution